# How can I retrieve array from my parse query using Java?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I tried to retrive my array from my ParseObject query , I couldnt find a way .
Any ideas ?

Comment: Show what you had tried

Comment: @SilentKiller Hey , I tried this :
String[] array = myParseObject.get("myArray");
But it didnt work :(
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

With Android, you have to use the function corresponding to the appropriate type. In this case it is [`getList:`](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#getList(java.lang.String)).

```
List<String> list = myParseObject.getList("myArray");
```

Comment: Did you notice the change? @user2697241

Comment: Your'e my H-E-R-O :)
Thank you !

Comment: Hey again , Just tried it again and its still not working ... here what i tried to do :
http://prntscr.com/4qh6th
Any ideas ?

Comment: Hey. Rather than adding on to existing questions it's good practice to create a new one with the new problem. If my solution worked here you should mark it as the answer and leave it as is in case future people encounter the same problem and need a solution. I'll look at it, but ask it as a new question and paste the link here. @user2697241

Comment: Yea i know , But I kind of passed my limit or somthing .
Its really important to me ... any ideas ?

Comment: Is it supposed to be: `setText(list[i].toString())`?

Comment: I think that its ok , but Im pretty sure that the problem is the :
 List<String> list = parseObject.getList("arr");
I think its returns null ...

Comment: Well that part is right, it worked before. Maybe parseObject doesn't include the arr column. That's a problem with your array. Ask a new question with your array. You have points so maybe you can ask it.

Comment: If this worked for you before then the answer is correct, you shouldn't uncheck it as being correct.